# How can I compare lines in a file using Perl?

Tags: perl

I need to compare lines in a file :

```
KB0005  1019    T   IFVATVPVI   0.691   PKC YES
KB0005  1036    T   YFLQTSQQL   0.785   PKC YES
KB0005  1037    S   FLQTSQQLK   0.585   DNAPK   YES
KB0005  1045    S   KQLESEGRS   0.669   PKC YES
KB0005  1045    S   KQLESEGRS   0.880   unsp    YES
KB204320    1019    T   IFVATVPVI   0.699   PKC YES
KB204320    1036    T   YFLQTSQQL   0.789   PKC YES
KB204320    1037    S   FLQTSQQLK   0.589   DNAPK   YES
KB204320    1045    S   KQLESEGRS   0.880   unsp    YES
```

I need to print the lines that differ or don't repeat, which I managed to do by first putting lines into 2 arrays (the lines differ in names `KB0005` and `KB204320`) and then by writing a perl script:

Code:

```
foreach $item (@a1, @a2) { $count{$item}++;}

foreach $item (keys %count) {
    if ($count{$item} == 2) {
        next;
    } else {
        push @diff, $item;
    }
}

my @sorted =sort @diff;
#print "\nIntersect Array = @isect\n";
foreach my $el(@sorted){
    print "$el\n";
}
```

Ouput:

```
1019 T IFVATVPVI 0.691 PKC
1019 T IFVATVPVI 0.699 PKC
1036 T YFLQTSQQL 0.785 PKC
1036 T YFLQTSQQL 0.789 PKC
1037 S FLQTSQQLK 0.585 DNAPK
1037 S FLQTSQQLK 0.589 DNAPK
1045 S KQLESEGRS 0.669 PKC
```

This works good, I just want to print from which line (KB005 or the other) a given line comes from.

How do I do this?

Comment: You should fix your formatting if you want anyone to seriously look at this question.

Comment: Answered as he has the most part of it. whether it is homework or not

Answer (score 1):

As you only want the ones with unique lines you could change the start to the following:

```
my %hash = ();
my $line = 0;

foreach my $item (@a1, @a2)
{ 
   $line++
   $hash{$item}{count}++;
   $hash{$item}{line} = $line;
}
close FH;

foreach $item (keys %hash) {
    if ($hash{$item} > 1) {
        next;
    } else {
        push @diff, $item;
    }
}

my @sorted = sort @diff;
my $lineNo = 0;

foreach my $el(@sorted){
    $lineNo = $hash{$el}{line};
    print "$el, $lineNo\n";
}
```

Or something very like that.  Create a more detailed hash structure.

This code is not tested, but the theory should be ok.

I dont understand the first part about reading into 2 arrays if the contents are from a single file.  You can overcome this by building the hash as you are reading the file:

```
 open FH, "file.txt";
 while (<FH>)
 { 
    my @items = split (/ /, $_);
    my $item = $items[0];
    $line++
    $hash{$item}{count}++;
    $hash{$item}{line} = $line;
 }
 close FH;
```

But I could be misunderstanding this part.

Hope this helps

**Update 1:**

I'm a bit confused. My task is to extract lines from this file which appear only once (either `KB0005` or `KB204320`) or lines which differs in value in column5.

So in the output I want to have, for example:

```
KB0005 has different value at position 1019 for PKC compared to KB204320 [0.691-0.699]
KB0005 has different value at position 1037 for DNAPK compared to KB204320 [0.585-0.589]
...
```

or

> `KB has additional record at position 1045 for PKC`

**Update 2:**

FM's solution is working. Can you tell me how can I combine this script with other files.

I have a list of pairs just like `KB0005` and `KB204320`, and I want to perform this action for every single of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [String::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/~yappo/String-Diff-0.04/) after you've filtered your items.